LINKING_ERROR in @google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native
I have integrated @google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native in my native app. It works fine on android but when I try to run it on IOS, I get this error
Error: The package '@google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure:

You have run 'pod install'
You rebuilt the app after installing the package
You are not using Expo Go

Also, when I build in xcode v15, I get these two errors

Module 'RecaptchaInterop' not found
Could not build Objective-C module 'RecaptchaEnterprise'

I did npm install, pod install multiple times, removed caches, cleared derivedFolder contents, added these lines in the Podfile as instructed in the recaptcha enterprise documentation

flipper_config = FlipperConfiguration.disabled
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

Now when I do npm start, the build gets stuck at some point
npm start logs
I have been able to open the app, and when I click on login I see this error
Error: The package '@google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native' doesn't seem to be linked.
I have been trying at this a lot but no use, recaptcha version I am using is 18.5.1, Also tried downgrading to 18.2.2 but no use. It is present in my podfile.lock but still getting the linking error.

recaptcha-enterprise-react-native (18.5.1):

glog
RCT-Folly (= 2022.05.16.00)
React-Core
RecaptchaEnterprise (= 18.5.1)


RecaptchaEnterprise (18.5.1):

RecaptchaInterop (~> 100.0.0)


RecaptchaInterop (100.0.0)


I resolved the issue by installing the latest version (18.5.1 as of today) of the @google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native package.
To accommodate both static and dynamic linkage requirements in my project, I added gem cocoapods-pod-linkage to the Gemfile and ran bundle install.
Next, I edited the Podfile:
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"
plugin 'cocoapods-pod-linkage'

platform :ios, '12.0'

# preinstall and post install scripts omitted

target 'AppTarget' do
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :dynamic
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    :hermes_enabled => true
  )

  # RecaptchaEnterprise requires static linkage
  pod 'RecaptchaInterop', '~> 100.0.0', :linkage => :static, 
    :modular_headers => true
  pod 'recaptcha-enterprise-react-native', :linkage => :static,
    :path => '../node_modules/@google-cloud/recaptcha-enterprise-react-native'
end

As a final step, I ran pod install and was then able to compile my project successfully.
I hope this solves your problem too :)
